# Multiple Pages redirect in classic asp

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, http-status-code-301

I was working on client side & found there were approx 30000 pages lying in old folder, as they created new pages for old urls around 3 years back, but didn't implemented 301 redirect at that time. 
Those pages are dynamically generating, so i asked my client's developer to 301 redirect these pages to new ones as old ones were also generating some traffic.
 Now developer says its not possible to redirect dynamically in classic Asp, so they have to implement page to page level redirection. 
Is it possible to redirect through 1 command in classic asp? As i am not developer so please explain me in layman language so i will be able to help client team

Comment: Can you clarify "Those pages are dynamically generating"; How will you be mapping old page -> new page - i.e. what's the rule - will you have equal number (30K) "new" pages?

Comment: Can you give an example of an old URL and the new URL?